# How to check if multiple ansible variables are defined without warnings?

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I have a task at the beginning of a role:

```
- name: check if pg_* variables are defined
  fail: msg="variable {{item}} is undefined"
  when: "{{item}} is undefined"
  with_items:
    - pg_dbname
    - pg_host
    - pg_port
    - pg_username
    - pg_password
```

But newer versions of Ansible raise the following warning:

> [WARNING]: when statements should not include jinja2 templating delimiters such as {{ }} or {% %}. Found: **{{item}} is undefined**

Removing the Jinja2 braces `when: item is undefined` doesn't work because the final evaluation is essentially equivalent to:

```
"pg_dbname" is undefined` # False
"pg_host" is undefined` # False
.
.
"pg_password" is undefined` # False
```

This is not what I want.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Variable called `item` is **always** defined inside `with_items` loop and your task should have `skipped` status for all five strings that you assign to it.

---

You want to check if the actual variable exists:

```
when: vars[item] is undefined
```

Comment: I knew there had to be a global dict that I could access using the string inside `item`. Thanks.